# Recording event payments that come by mail (checks) after online registration

Tags: civievent, iats

My civiCRM instance: civiCRM: 5.37.0. + iATS Extension: 1.7.4
Drupal: 7.80

My management insisted that we offer a "Pay Later" option for an event with  online registration. Checks are coming in but I can't get back into the participant's record to change the payment amount.

I go to the participant's record > Events > on the event row I select Edit.

There is a "Change Selections" link which takes we to another screen with the link "View Payments." Clicking this link produces a box that declares "No payments found for this participant > Record Payment > etc.

When I click "Record Payment" I get the message "Unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page...and try again." Refreshing takes me back to the participant's record.

So, how do I update a participant's record to acknowledge payment?

Comment: While @Demerit's answer is probably the easiest way to go, it's worth checking out why you get an "Unable to reach the server" error when clicking "Record Payment".  I would enable Debugging and Backtrace at CiviCRM's **Administer menu » System Settings » Debugging and Error Handling**.  Then, right-click the "Record Payments" link and open it in a new tab.  You should get a more detailed error.  If the error doesn't make the solution obvious, you can post the error and backtrace as a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Don't click Change Selections - instead on that edit page change the participant status from Pay Later to Registered, and then lower down in the Payment Information section change the payment status to Completed.